# error: "invoking make failed"

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hello, when I run catkin_make I get the following errors:

```
Scanning dependencies of target gira
[100%] Building CXX object prueba/CMakeFiles/gira.dir/src/gira.cpp.o
Linking CXX executable /home/turtlebot/catkin_ws/devel/lib/proyecto/gira
CMakeFiles/gira.dir/src/gira.cpp.o: In function `main':
gira.cpp:(.text+0x55): undefined reference to `ros::init(int&, char**, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, unsigned int)'
gira.cpp:(.text+0xa5): undefined reference to `ros::NodeHandle::NodeHandle...
```

any idea what could be the mistake? thanks

the executable gira.cpp:

```
#include "ros/ros.h"   
#include "geometry_msgs/Twist.h"  

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

ros::init(argc, argv, "gira");   

    ros::NodeHandle n;

    ros::Publisher vel_pub_=n.advertise<geometry_msgs::Twist>("cmd_vel", 1);   

    geometry_msgs::Twist vel;

    ros::Rate loop_rate(10);   

    while (ros::ok())   
    {
        vel.linear.x = 0.1;   //velocidad de avance
        vel.angular.z = 0.3;   //velocidad de giro

        vel_pub_.publish(vel);

        loop_rate.sleep();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

the CMakeLists.txt (catkin specific configuration and built) :

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(prueba)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS geometry_msgs image_transport nav_msgs roscpp  sensor_msgs std_msgs )

catkin_package(
INCLUDE_DIRS include

## LIBRARIES prueba

## CATKIN_DEPENDS geometry_msgs image_transport nav_msgs roscpp sensor_msgs std_msgs turtlebot_node

## DEPENDS system_lib

)

### Specify additional locations of header files

### Your package locations should be listed before other locations

include_directories(include
${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

### Declare a cpp library

## add_library(prueba

## src/${PROJECT_NAME}/prueba.cpp

## )

### Declare a cpp executable

## add_executable(prueba_node src/prueba_node.cpp)

add_executable(gira src/gira.cpp)

### Add cmake target dependencies of the executable/library

### as an example, message headers may need to be generated before nodes

## add_dependencies(prueba_node prueba_generate_messages_cpp)

### Specify libraries to link a library or executable target against

## target_link_libraries(prueba_node

## ${catkin_LIBRARIES}

## )

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/67418/error:-%22invoking-make-failed%22/) by [albarranco](https://answers.ros.org/users/5345/albarranco/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2013-07-15

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Asfandyar Ashraf Malik](https://answers.ros.org/users/5044/asfandyar-ashraf-malik/) on 2013-07-15**:
It seems that the problem is with your code. Without the code, its quite hard to figure out the solution to this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Undefined references indicate linker problems. It seems like the linker cannot find any ROS related symbols. Are you sure you have your `package.xml` and `CMakeLists.txt` setup properly?

---

Originally posted by [ipso](https://answers.ros.org/users/2486/ipso/) with karma: 1416 on 2013-07-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [albarranco](https://answers.ros.org/users/5345/albarranco/) on 2013-07-16**:
I've only added to CMakeLists.txt add_executable(gira src/gira.cpp). Do I have to change something else in the CMakeLists.txt or package.xml?

**Comment by [ipso](https://answers.ros.org/users/2486/ipso/) on 2013-07-16**:
Then please post the contents of your CMakeLists.txt (add it to your original question).

**Comment by [albarranco](https://answers.ros.org/users/5345/albarranco/) on 2013-10-18**:
Solved, I forgot to add target_link_libraries (gira $ {catkin_LIBRARIES}) to CMakeList.txt.
Thanks